# Reading file from Google Drive with Talend

Tags: talend

I need to read an uploaded file in Google Drive and perform X transformation with it. As per my reading, the single way to do it is by downloading the file to my local machine with the Talend component and then, reading from there.

If it is correct, I cannot figure what would be the file name assuming that I don't want to use the exact name of the file.

I found http://meowbi.com/2018/02/23/getting-google-sheet-gdrive-talend/ and it is exactly what I need - read from Google Drive, check the file name and proceed if the file name is X. What is unclear for me is what they used in tJava.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output schema of `tGoogleDriveList` component's `Main` row contains a field `name` that is the file name you're looking for. Using `Iterate` row is less straightforward as you need to extract values from GlobalMap. In the article you cited they get file name by `"tGoogleDriveList_1_TITLE"` key of the GlobalMap.

[Main row between tGoogleDriveList and tJava](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GObj.png)

For more details please look into the [Talend Reference for Google Drive components](https://help.talend.com/reader/Vr1yjduy7_q1pVrhImTzAQ/cYNygOETYymRC0WieZPhYg). The **Listing files and folders in Google Drive** section should be particularly topical for your case.